# Extracting everything after first two words in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract all the info, using a regular expression in R, after the first number and first word of an entry in a data frame.

For example:

```
Header = 
c("2006 Volvo XC70", 
"2012 Ford Econoline Cargo Van E-250 Commercial", 
"2012 Nissan Frontier", 
"2012 Kia Soul 5dr Wagon Automatic")
```

I want to write a pattern that will grab ***Volvo XC70***, or ***Econoline Cargo Van E-250 Commercial*** (everything after the year and make) from an entry in my "header" column so that I may run the function on my data frame and create a new "model" column. I can't figure out a pattern that will allow me to skip the first string of integers, then a space, then the first string of characters, and then a space, and then grab everything proceeding.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What if the make has two words, like Aston Martin or Mercedes Benz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use sub.

```
sub("^\\d+\\s+\\w+\\s+", "", df$x)
```

*Example:*

```
x <- "2012 Ford Econoline Cargo Van E-250 Commercial"
sub("^\\d+\\s+\\w+\\s+", "", x)
# [1] "Econoline Cargo Van E-250 Commercial"
```

Answer (score 2):

For this task, I would fetch a basic list using the **XML** package:

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlParse('http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/ympg/shared/menu/make')
```

Now that we fetched the XML data we can create a vector with the car makes:

```
mk <- xpathSApply(doc, '//value', xmlValue)
```

Finally, I'll compile the pattern and play around with [`sprintf`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html) and [`sub`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html):

```
df$Makes <- sub(sprintf('\\d+ (?:%s) ', paste(mk, collapse='|')), '', df$Header)
```

Output:

```
##                                          Header
# 1                                2006 Volvo XC70
# 2 2012 Ford Econoline Cargo Van E-250 Commercial
# 3                           2012 Nissan Frontier
# 4              2012 Kia Soul 5dr Wagon Automatic

##                                           Makes
# 1                                           XC70
# 2           Econoline Cargo Van E-250 Commercial
# 3                                       Frontier
# 4                       Soul 5dr Wagon Automatic
```